# A path-connected graph is connected as a graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, connectedness, path-connected

This question regards the difference between being path-connected as a topological space, i.e. "Every two point $x,y \in X$ can be connected with a path" and being connected in a graph sense: "A graph $G$ is connected if there is a path in $G$ between any pair of distinct vertices."

I can see that being connected in a graph sense implies being path connected in a topological sense, but how do I show that being path connected in a topological sense implies being connected as a graph (at least for finite graphs)?

Comment: Both say that there is a path between any two vertices, I don’t see what the problem is.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter The problem is that the word "path" means different thing in each context. In graph theory it is a sequence of vertices $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ such that there is an edge between $(v_i, v_{i+1})$. In topology it is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to G$. Note that here by $G$ we understand [the topological realization of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(topology)).

Comment: And as OP noted every graph path induces topological path. This is quite obvious, because every edge between $(v,w)$ induces a topological path. This is an immediate consequence of the construction of the topological realization. But the other way around seems harder. In other words: how to extract a sequence of vertices and edges from a given path $[0,1]\to G$? Note subtleties: for example a topological path can pass infinitely many times through vertices (even in a finite graph). This cannot happen for a graph path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with vertices $V$ and edges $E$. Let $T(G)$ be its [topological realization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(topology)). I will use the following fact

> **Lemma.** If $G$ is a disjoint union of two subgraphs then $T(G)$ is a (topological) disjoint union of two spaces, each one being a topological realization of appropriate subgraphs of $G$. Furthermore if $v,w\in V$ lie in different (graph) components then $v,w$ lie in different connected components of $T(G)$.

*Proof.* Assume that that $G=G_1\sqcup G_2$ as graphs, i.e. $G=G_1\cup G_2$ and there is no path between $G_1$ and $G_2$. Consider $T(G_1)$ and $T(G_2)$ which are subsets of $T(G)$. It can be easily seen that $T(G_1)\cap T(G_2)=\emptyset$. Otherwise there would be either an edge between $G_1$ and $G_2$ or they would share a vertex. Since both $T(G_1)$ and $T(G_2)$ are closed (as full subgraphs always are) then $T(G)=T(G_1)\sqcup T(G_2)$. $\Box$

As you've noted it is trivial to see that every graph path induces topological path because edges correspond to subspaces of $T(G)$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Now assume that $\lambda:[0,1]\to T(G)$ is a path between two vertices $v,w$. Assume that there is no graph path from $v$ to $w$. It follows that $G$ is a disjoint union of two subgraphs: one containing $v$ (the graph path component of $v$) and the other containing $w$ (the complement). By the lemma this implies that $T(G)$ is a disjoint union of appropriate topological realizations. In particular $v,w$ lie in different connected components and thus cannot be connected by a path. Contradiction.